# How can I retun a list of absolute paths?

Tags: python, absolute-path

The following code returns a list of file-names in a given directory:

```
def get_files(dir_path_str):
    onlyfiles = next(os.walk(dir_path_str))[2]
    return onlyfiles
```

How can I make it return absolute file paths with minimal modification and preserve the behavior of the function?

Comment: Try `[os.path.join(dir_path_str, fn) for fn in onlyfiles]`

Comment: An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should say what the actual behaviour is in addition to the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Make your input directory a Path object, use .iterdir() to get all the files/folders inside that directory, use .absolute() to make them absolute and .is_file() to check that they're files:

```
from pathlib import Path


def get_files(inp_path_str):
    directory = Path(inp_path_str)
    only_files = [file.absolute() for file in directory.iterdir() if file.is_file()]
    return only_files
```

If you want the paths to be strings rather than Path objects, pathlib Paths can have str() called on them:

```
only_files = [str(file.absolute()) for file in directory.iterdir() if file.is_file()]
```

Or as a fully expanded loop rather than a list comprehension:

```
def get_files(inp_path_str):
    directory = Path(inp_path_str)
    only_files = []
    for file in directory.iterdir():
        if file.is_file():
            only_files.append(str(file.absolute()))
    return only_files
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  It will get the absolute path to the top level and append it to all the files in the top level...

```
import os

def get_files(dir_path_str):
    top_level = next(os.walk(dir_path_str))
    onlyfiles = top_level[2]
    abs_path = os.path.abspath(top_level[0])
    files = [os.path.join(abs_path, f) for f in onlyfiles]
    return files
```